# General algebraic solution for ordinary inhomogenous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we want to solve a differential equation like
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a(t)x+f(t)$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow\ \frac{dx}{dt}-a(t)x=f(t)$$
and use integrating factor (I know there are other methods, but I want to know how to do it using integrating factor), where integrating factor is $e^{-\int a(t) dt}$. We multiply each term with the integrating factor and get:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}e^{-\int a(t) dt}-a(t)xe^{-\int a(t) dt}=f(t)e^{-\int a(t) dt}$$
This can be rewritten as:
$$(xe^{-\int a(t) dt})'=f(t)e^{-\int a(t) dt}$$
Integration of each side of the equation leads to:
$$xe^{-\int a(t) dt}=\int f(t)e^{-\int a(t) dt} dt$$
If we use integration by parts ($\int fg=Fg-\int Fg'$) we get:
$$xe^{-\int a(t) dt}=F(t)e^{-\int a(t) dt}+\int F(t)a(t)e^{-\int a(t)dt} dt$$
Division of both sides with $e^{-\int a(t) dt}$ gives
$$x=F(t)-e^{\int a(t)dt}\int F(t)a(t)e^{-\int a(t)dt} dt$$
I'm not sure how to continue from here. Are the calculations correct so far? Is it possible to simplify them further for a general algebraic solution?

Comment: I think that $$x(t)=e^{\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}x(0)+\int_0^t{e^{\int_s^t{a(r)dr}}f(s)ds}$$ is the most simplified version you can have unless you consider extra assumptions for $a(t),f(t)$. So your analysis is correct.

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly did you do here? I see you changed the variable 't' to 's' at some places and 'r' at others and added intervals to the integrals, but I have no idea what the logic is behind this. How did you get from the equations I wrote to what you wrote? Please explain every step!

Comment: I posted an answer to see the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply the ODE by $e^{-\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}$ then you have that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[x(t)e^{-\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}-\int_0^t{f(s)e^{-\int_0^s{a(r)dr}}ds}\right]=0$$
Now integrating over $[0,t]$ we result in
$$x(t)e^{-\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}-\int_0^t{f(s)e^{-\int_0^s{a(r)dr}}ds}=x(0)$$
Multiplying by $e^{\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}$ we derive
$$x(t)=x(0)e^{\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}+e^{\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}\int_0^t{f(s)e^{-\int_0^s{a(r)dr}}ds}$$
or equivalently
$$x(t)=x(0)e^{\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}+\int_0^t{f(s)e^{\int_s^t{a(s)ds}}ds}$$

Comment: I'm confused at the first step. Firstly, which of the expressions that I wrote is it that you are multiplying with $e^{-\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}$?

Secondly, where does $f(s)$ come from, there is no such term in what I wrote, it seems you are chaing the variable $t$ to $s$, but only for the term $f(t)$ which becomes $f(s)$, while $x(t)$ is still a variable of $t$. Why do you change the variables like this?

Thirdly you have a $a(r)$ instead of $a(s)$? Where does the $r$ come from? What does it stand for? Why is this variable necessary, and why do you change it in this particular place and not others?

Comment: The first multiplication is for the state equation $\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x(t)+f(t)$. I do not see any confusion in the integration variables since $f(t)e^{-\int_0^t{a(s)ds}}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\int_0^t{f(s)e^{-\int_0^s{a(r)dr}} ds}\right]$

Comment: Ok, so if we multiply $\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x(t)+f(t)$ with $e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}$ we get: $$\dot{x}(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}=a(t)x(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}+f(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}$$ I really don't understand how that becomes what you wrote? Please try EXPLAINING what you are doing in each step to make it become another expression. It is not obvious.

Comment: CTNT, I would appreciate if you could explain what you are doing, since I don't understand it.

Comment: The last equation you wrote in your comment becomes directly the first equation in my reply. You simply use the fact that $F(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t{F(s)ds}$  with $F(t)=f(t)e^{-\int_0^t{a(r)dr}}$.